# Table- Parsing (Kendo UI Grid): Capturing the details of the model being sent from the View to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The main issue here is validating a Kendo Grid - with an InCell edit setting.

Kendo UI grid is no more than a 'Glorified table' - it is a Html table in the end, hence my tagging of JQuery and JavaScript into this question!

This is the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Timeshet.Web.Models.UserModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("This user will now be removed from the grid. \n\n To commit this delete make sure you click Save Changes button !"))
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                                 {
                                     //columns.Bound(p => p.UserId);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Forename);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Surname);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Txtname);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Mobile);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.HolidayEntitlement);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Password);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Level);
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkboxActive' #= Active ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>");
                                     columns.Bound(p => p.UserAccess);
                                     columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100).Visible(User.IsInRole(Constants.Admin)).Hidden();
                                 })
   // .Events(events => events.SaveChanges("validateInputOnSaveChanges"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.UserId))
        .Batch(true)
        //.Events(events=>events.Change("validateInputOnSaveChanges"))
        .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
//        .Events(events => events.RequestStart("requestStart"))
        .Events(events =>  events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
        .Create(update => update.Action("UserCreate", "User"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("UserRead", "User").Data("ExtraData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UserUpdate", "User"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("UserDelete", "User"))
                )
      )
```

As you see, it has inCell edit mode, whose validation is proving difficult.

I have tried to Parse the grid and look for the k-dirty-class which gets enabled on an edited cell like this. I was doing this on saveChanges event of the grid, which gets fired when the save changes button is clicked:

```
$("#Grid tbody").find('td').each(
    function () {
        debugger;

        // run for specific columns - where validation is needed
      //  var isDirty = cellToValidate.hasClass('k-dirty-cell');

       var isDirty = $(this).hasClass('k-dirty-cell');
        if (isDirty == true) {

            var cellContent = $(this).context.innerText;
            var cellIndex = $(this).context.cellIndex;

            alert(cellContent + cellIndex);

        }
    });
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that when a User creates a new user (row) and enters the Forename and Surname and save - the grid doesn't validate the TxtName column, because it is set to InCell edit mode where only clicked cells get validated as per the view-model.

This has to be done in the InCell edit mode. Inline Editing works, but it is not the requirement here.

My plan is to validate the input on dirty cells but this is also is proving difficult, because not all dirty cells need validating but only the TextName column!

I wonder if there is anyway I could capture the details of the new row being sent to the controller, which is basically the view-model?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a validation method for the saveChanges event that loops through the grid rows

You could loop through the rows like so:

```
var currentRows = grid.tbody.find("tr");
```

Once you have your rows, you'll need to grab each dataItem ( *grid.dataItem(currentRows[i])* )  and then check a property that you can be certain that an inserted row wont yet have assigned.

For our particular model we used a property called model.ticketID because the ticket ID was only created after a DB insert.

From here, you can set up your own validation for the row, or you can flip on editable for the row, and use the kendo recommended approach for validation.

Comment: please see my solution above if you like and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be having/ or may have this issue; this is how I ended up solving it:

I used the  grid's saveChanges event to find dirty cells, then from there get to the parent row, then from there navigate to the cell that needs to be validated; get its text and do the validation - in my case I only wanted to validated if the input value is not null:

```
//On Kendo UI grid: 

.Events(events => events.SaveChanges("validateInputOnSaveChanges"))
```

// The JavaScript function:

```
function validateInputOnSaveChanges(e) {
    //Validate TxtName field
    var columnIndex = 3; // Index of the column to validate

    $("#Grid tr td").each(function () {

        var dirty = $(this).hasClass('k-dirty-cell');

        if (dirty == true) {
            var TxtName = $(this).parent().children()[columnIndex].innerText; // Get the text input in this field

            if (TxtName === "") { // validate
                e.preventDefault(true); // halt the Create function of DataSource
                alert("Txt Name Cannot be Blank.");
                return false; // quit the loop
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Kind regards, 
t_plusplus